# Solving ODE in power series about infinity

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion

I want to solve a particular ODE in power series of 1/x. I can obtain the power series solution about x=0. Can any one suggest how to obtain a series solution in 1/x for the following ODE?

I tried the following which did not work. (Mainly the `LogicalExpand` doesn't seem to work.)

Changed variable : w =1/x

```
F := Sum[p[i] (a L w)^i, {i, 0, 4}]

DE = 1/16 ((
  16 (a^2) (
   L^2) ((1 + a L w)^4) (W^2) )/((1 + 
     2 a L w)^2 (1 + 2 a L w (1 + a L w))^2) - (
  a^2 L^2 W (4 I + W))/(1 + 
    a L w)^2 + (
  8 (-1 - 2 a L w + 2 a^3 L^3 w^3) (I a L W ))/(
  w (1 + a L w) (1 + 2 a L w) (1 + 
     2 a L w (1 + a L w)))) D[F, { w, 0}] + 
 1/16  ((8 I a L W)/(1 + a L w) + (
  8 (-1 - 2 a L w + 2 a^3 L^3 w^3) (4 (1 + a L w)))/(
  w (1 + a L w) (1 + 2 a L w) (1 + 
     2 a L w (1 + a L w)))) D[F, {w, 1}] + 
 D[F, {w, 2}] == 0


coeffeqns = LogicalExpand[DE]

solvedcoeffs = Solve[coeffeqns, Reverse[Table[p[i], {i, 0, 4}]]]

F = F /. solvedcoeffs
```

Comment: Reference(s) to smarter code for power series solution will also be  appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two issues here. The first is that [`LogicalExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogicalExpand.html) is for expanding **logical expressions**, like so:

```
In[1]:= LogicalExpand[(a || b) && (b || c)]
Out[1]= (a || b) && (b || c)
```

Second, you can actually work directly with power series and expand them about $ \infty $, as follows:

```
In[2]:= series = Series[f[(a L /x)], {x, Infinity, 4}];
```

In Mathematica, this is a `SeriesData` object that represents the series in a compact way, but you can do many normal operations on it. Using [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html) to get nice output for SE yields:

$$ f(0)+\frac{a L f'(0)}{x}+\frac{a^2 L^2 f''(0)}{2 x^2}+\frac{a^3 f^{(3)}(0) L^3}{6
   x^3}+\frac{a^4 f^{(4)}(0) L^4}{24 x^4}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^5\right) $$

However, for the rest of the problem, I'll use your definition in terms of $ w = \frac{1}{x} $. Let's use your `DE` definition and substitute in the series for `f[a L w]` before taking the derivatives using `Block`:

```
ode = Block[{F = Series[f[a*L*w], {w, 0, 4}]}, 
  Simplify[(1/16)*((16*a^2*L^2*(1 + a*L*w)^4*W^2)/((1 + 2*a*L*w)^2*
         (1 + 2*a*L*w*(1 + a*L*w))^2) - (a^2*L^2*W*(4*I + W))/
        (1 + a*L*w)^2 + (8*(-1 - 2*a*L*w + 2*a^3*L^3*w^3)*(I*a*L*W))/
        (w*(1 + a*L*w)*(1 + 2*a*L*w)*(1 + 2*a*L*w*(1 + a*L*w))))*
      D[F, {w, 0}] + (1/16)*((8*I*a*L*W)/(1 + a*L*w) + 
       (8*(-1 - 2*a*L*w + 2*a^3*L^3*w^3)*(4*(1 + a*L*w)))/
        (w*(1 + a*L*w)*(1 + 2*a*L*w)*(1 + 2*a*L*w*(1 + a*L*w))))*
      D[F, {w, 1}] + D[F, {w, 2}] == 0]];
```

The Mathematica output is kinda gross, so I'll `TeXForm` it again:

$$ \frac{a L \left(-2 f'(0)-\frac{1}{2} i f(0) W\right)}{w}+\frac{1}{16} a^2 L^2 \left(-16
   f''(0)+64 f'(0)+15 f(0) W^2+20 i f(0) W\right)+\frac{1}{16} a^3 L^3 w \left(W^2
   \left(15 f'(0)-62 f(0)\right)-4 i W \left(-f''(0)-3 f'(0)+8 f(0)\right)+64
   \left(f''(0)-f'(0)\right)\right)+\frac{1}{96} a^4 L^4 w^2 \left(W^2 \left(45
   f''(0)-372 f'(0)+942 f(0)\right)+4 i W \left(4 f^{(3)}(0)+3 f''(0)-36 f'(0)+66
   f(0)\right)+16 \left(f^{(4)}(0)+12 f^{(3)}(0)-24 f''(0)+24
   f'(0)\right)\right)+O\left(w^3\right)=0 $$

As you can see, this equation is given in terms of $ \left\{f(0),f'(0),f''(0),f^{(3)}(0),f^{(4)}(0)\right\} $. Assuming $ f(0) $ and $ f'(0) $ are fixed (since it's a second-order ODE), we can reduce `ode` for non-zero $ a $ and $ L $:

```
reduced = Assuming[{a != 0, L != 0}, 
   Refine[Reduce[ode, Array[Derivative[#1][f][0] & , 3, 2]]]];
```

Here,

```
In[4]:= Array[Derivative[#1][f][0] &, 3, 2]
Out[4]= {Derivative[2][f][0], Derivative[3][f][0], Derivative[4][f][0]}
```

is just a compact way of describing the derivatives we want to solve for, [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) attempts to eliminate the listed variables from the equation, and [`Refine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html) applies the assumptions (set by [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html)) that $ a \ne 0 $ and $ L \ne 0 $.

Which comes out to

$$    \left(f'(0)=0\land f(0)=0\land f''(0)=0\land f^{(4)}(0)=-i f^{(3)}(0) (W-12
   i)\right)\lor \left(f(0)\neq 0\land W=\frac{4 i f'(0)}{f(0)}\land f''(0)=\frac{1}{4}
   i (15 W+4 i) f'(0)\land f^{(4)}(0)=-\frac{1}{64} i \left(64 f^{(3)}(0) W-768 i
   f^{(3)}(0)+675 W^3 f'(0)+1848 i W^2 f'(0)+8688 W f'(0)+1152 i f'(0)\right)\right) $$

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I couldn't quite follow the last part of your code. Can you please elaborate on this..

Comment: Which last part? Where I define `reduced`?

Comment: Yes, that part only.

Comment: I do not understand why `LogicalExpand` doesn't work for my code..

Comment: `DE`, which you're trying to expand, doesn't have any logical operations (`And`, `Or`, `Not`, et c.) to expand. You only have a single equation.

Comment: But near `x=0`  this works fine. I mean the LHS of the `DE` is actually a polynomial in `x`  and the `LogicalExpand` equates each coeff of the polynomial to zero.

Comment: @pinu: Holy cow! You're right. It also works on my `ode` definition. I'll think about revising my post, but I have to explore what's going on....